# HTMLからjavascriptにサイズの大きなデータを渡したいです

Tags: javascript, html5

HTML5＋SpringBootで勉強をしています。

HTMLからjavasript側に以下のようにデータを渡しています。

```
th:onclick="|show('${test.data1}', '${test.data2}');|
```

渡すデータが小さい場合特に問題なく値がわたっているのですが、
（jsファイルにブレイクを張って確認できました）
画像データのようにサイズが大きな場合、以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

大きなデータをjavascript側に渡す方法は何かありますでしょうか。

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
```

〇jsファイル

```
function show(data1, data2) {
}
```

Comment: HTMLの適当な要素に埋め込み関数にはそのIDを渡すというのはどうでしょうか

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！なるほど。そうですね！試してみたところエラーも起こらず取得可能でした！通常、そのようなやり方を行うのが普通なのでしょうか？今回はデータが２つでしたので、それで実施したのですが、例えばリスト型のデータでデータ数が多量にある場合も同じような方法で実施するのでしょうか？

Comment: 普通かどうかは知りません。リスト型データがどんなものかは知りませんが、何とでもなるような気がします。

Answer (score 2):

`画像データのようにサイズが大きな`ファイルを参照する場合、HTMLに埋め込んでしまうと（JavaScriptにせよ、HTMLにせよ、Base64にせよ）ページ全体の読み込みが遅れてしまうため、**別ファイル、またはAPIを用意し、そちらへの参照を渡すようにする**のが一般的な構成だと考えます。

また、蛇足ですが `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal` は以下のいずれかが原因のエラーであり、サイズの問題ではなさそうです。

> このエラーを修正するためには、次の点をチェックしてください：
>
> - 文字列リテラルのために、クオート（シングルかダブル）の開始と終了を行っている。
> - 文字列リテラルを正しくエスケープしている。
> - 文字列リテラルが複数行に分けられていない。
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unterminated_string_literal